# Reverse a JSON file

Tags: json

I have a JSON file with mime types like this:

```json
{
    "video/quicktime": ["mov", "qt"],
    "video/vnd.dece.hd": ["uvh", "uvvh"],
    "video/vnd.dece.mobile": ["uvm", "uvvm"],
    "video/vnd.dece.pd": ["uvp", "uvvp"],
    "video/vnd.dece.sd": ["uvs", "uvvs"],
    "video/vnd.dece.video": ["uvv", "uvvv"],
    "video/vnd.dvb.file": ["dvb"],
    "video/vnd.fvt": ["fvt"],
    "video/vnd.mpegurl": ["m4u", "mxu"],
    "video/vnd.ms-playready.media.pyv": ["pyv"],
    "video/vnd.uvvu.mp4": ["uvu", "uvvu"],
}
```

it goes on for like 800 lines, so by hand is not a choice.

I now need to reverse this array to

```json
{
    "mov": "video/quicktime",
    "qt": "video/quicktime",
    "uvh": "video/dece.hd"

}
```

and so on.

Can I do this?

Comment: This looks like a job for a throwaway script in whatever programming language you're comfortable with - parse the JSON, loop over it, and build the new structure. It would be no more than a dozen lines in PHP, for instance. Pattern matching (e.g. regex) is going to be much more fiddly, because you have to account for all the different possible list lengths on the right-hand side.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the solution is probably to write a script, but no programming language was mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this little program in C#:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ReverseJson
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jsonText = @"{
                    'video/quicktime': ['mov', 'qt'],
                    'video/vnd.dece.hd': ['uvh', 'uvvh'],
                    'video/vnd.dece.mobile': ['uvm', 'uvvm'],
                    'video/vnd.dece.pd': ['uvp', 'uvvp'],
                    'video/vnd.dece.sd': ['uvs', 'uvvs'],
                    'video/vnd.dece.video': ['uvv', 'uvvv'],
                    'video/vnd.dvb.file': ['dvb'],
                    'video/vnd.fvt': ['fvt'],
                    'video/vnd.mpegurl': ['m4u', 'mxu'],
                    'video/vnd.ms-playready.media.pyv': ['pyv'],
                    'video/vnd.uvvu.mp4': ['uvu', 'uvvu'],
                }";
            
            var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonText);

            var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var item in json)
            {
                string media = item.Name;
                foreach (var extension in item.Value)
                {
                    string ext = extension.Value;
                    if (!dict.ContainsKey(ext))
                    {
                        dict.Add(ext, media);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict,Formatting.Indented));
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
{
  "mov": "video/quicktime",
  "qt": "video/quicktime",
  "uvh": "video/vnd.dece.hd",
  "uvvh": "video/vnd.dece.hd",
  "uvm": "video/vnd.dece.mobile",
  "uvvm": "video/vnd.dece.mobile",
  "uvp": "video/vnd.dece.pd",
  "uvvp": "video/vnd.dece.pd",
  "uvs": "video/vnd.dece.sd",
  "uvvs": "video/vnd.dece.sd",
  "uvv": "video/vnd.dece.video",
  "uvvv": "video/vnd.dece.video",
  "dvb": "video/vnd.dvb.file",
  "fvt": "video/vnd.fvt",
  "m4u": "video/vnd.mpegurl",
  "mxu": "video/vnd.mpegurl",
  "pyv": "video/vnd.ms-playready.media.pyv",
  "uvu": "video/vnd.uvvu.mp4",
  "uvvu": "video/vnd.uvvu.mp4"
}
```

A word of caution: this only works if no extension is associated with more than one media type. This is implied by the specified output format in the question.

Comment: Yes, this does the job, I kind of had a row with the Newtonsoft.Json lib and nuGet, but it works now, thanks.